# How do I convert this code generated by postman to a request using axios?

Tags: javascript, axios, httprequest

Here is the code generated by postman below

```
var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("image", fileInput.files[0], "/path/to/file");
  formdata.append("imageType", "Image_URL_1");
  formdata.append("userID", "3");
  formdata.append("password", "dsddfsdfsdf");
  formdata.append("userImage", "");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:3000/uploadUserImage", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))`enter code here`
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

'

I have tried to convert this to `axios` with some luck in that it will hit the API and not return network error, however, it will then return `req` is `undefined`.

here is my current axios call

```
async createFile(result){
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", result, result.uri);
formData.append("imageType", "Image_URL_1");
formData.append("userID", this.state.userID);
formData.append("password", this.state.password);

try{
  const res = await axios.post('http://162.249.2.147:3000/uploadUserImage', {
    formData,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'form-data',
    },
  })
  .then(function(){ console.log('SUCCESS!!'); })
} catch(e){ console.log(e)}
```

}

Comment: Posting your axios call code will help us to help you @Andrew Garrett.

Comment: Thanks @Jebin I have just updated the question now :)

Comment: Try sending formData as data and content type as `form-data` as given below.

    `data: formDarta,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the formdata with the key `data`.

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", result, result.uri);
    formData.append("imageType", "Image_URL_1");
    formData.append("userID", this.state.userID);
    formData.append("password", this.state.password);

    try {
        const res = await axios
            .post("http://162.249.2.147:3000/uploadUserImage", {
                data: formData,
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
            })
            .then(function () {
                console.log("SUCCESS!!");
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```